# How to display only one image in ezpublish JS slider

Tags: javascript, slider

I'm a beginner php developer, and have a shockingly poor fluency in Javascript. An ezpublish website I'm working on has this slider in as a default piece of code, but it displays three items. How can I edit it to show only 1 item? The code is:

(function() {

YUI( YUI3_config ).use( 'node', 'event', 'io-ez', function(Y, result) {

Y.on('domready', function(e) {

```
var offset = 0;
var limit = 1;
var total = {$block.valid_nodes|count()};

var handleRequest = function(e) {

    var className = e.target.get('className');
    if ( className == 'carousel-next-button' ) {

        offset += 1;

        if ( offset > total )
            offset = 0;
    }

    if ( className == 'carousel-prev-button' ) {

        var diff = total - offset;

        if( offset == 0 )
            offset = 0;
        else
            offset -= 1;
    }

    var colContent = Y.Node.all('#block-3 .col-content');
    colContent.each(function(n, e) {

        n.addClass('loading');
        var height = n.get('region').bottom - n.get('region').top;
        n.setStyle('height', height + 'px');
        n.set('innerHTML', '');
    });

    var data = 'http_accept=json&offset=' + offset;
    data += '&limit=' + limit;
    data += '&block_id={$block.id}';

    Y.io.ez( 'ezflow::getvaliditems', { on: { success: _callBack 
}, method: 'POST', data: data } );
};

var _callBack = function(id, o) {

    if ( o.responseJSON !== undefined ) {

        var response = o.responseJSON;
        var colContent = Y.Node.all('#block-{$block.id} .col-content');

        for(var i = 0; i < colContent.size(); i++) {

            var colNode = colContent.item(i);
            if ( response.content[i] !== undefined )
                colNode.set('innerHTML', response.content[i] );
        }
    }
};

    var prevButton = Y.one('#block-{$block.id} input.carousel-prev-button');
    prevButton.on('click', handleRequest);

    var nextButton = Y.one('#block-{$block.id} input.carousel-next-button');
    nextButton.on('click', handleRequest);

});
});

})();
</script>
```

A hand with this would be great x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like this code loads each item after the user clicks `prevButton` or `nextButton`. So the simplest way to force only a single item to display is probably to hide those buttons.

Without the markup it's hard to say what the optimal solution is, but I would try to find out what makes the particular markup you're working with into a carousel (I'd guess a class containing "carousel") and remove that so that it's just a single item without the carousel functionality.

For what it's worth, this question is not specific to eZ Publish or PHP so I'd consider removing those tags.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to StackOverflow, so the feedback on tags is great.

Comment: Your suggestion about hiding the buttons seems to be helping. I think I can work it out from here, Thanks again!